# How declare an enum that is in another class?

Tags: c++, qt, enums, enumeration

I have an enum in one class :

```
class SettingManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum BookDisplayKinds{
        BookDisplay1=0,
        BookDisplay2=1,
    };
    Q_ENUMS(BookDisplayKinds)
};
```

I want to declare an property in another class

```
#include<settingmanager.h>
class BookManager : public NetworkManager
{
  private:    
     SettingManager::BookDisplayKinds m_BookDisplayKind;//Error is here
};
```

but I got below error:

> 'SettingManager' does not name a type

I add forward delcalration of SettingManager before BookManager

```
#include<settingmanager.h>
class SettingManager;
class BookManager : public NetworkManager
{
  private:    
     SettingManager::BookDisplayKinds m_BookDisplayKind;//Error is here
};
```

But now I have below error

> 'BookDisplayKinds' in 'class SettingManager' does not name a type

Comment: Your declaration is syntactically correct. The symptoms point to a missing `#include` for the header of `SettingManager` class. Note that a mere forward declaration would not be sufficient.

Comment: Did you try to include header where `SettingManager` declared?

Comment: Your question is off-topic, since it lacks an MCVE. Considering that it's probably a misinterpretation and/or misrepresentation, I think it shows why that is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch to strong enum available since C++11. I recommend you to put it out of the class.

```
// SettingManager.h header
enum class BookDisplayKinds{
        BookDisplay1=0,
        BookDisplay2=1,
};
class SettingManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
};
```

Now it is possible to do a forward declaration like this:

```
// BookManager.h header
enum class BookDisplayKinds; // forward declaration
class BookManager : public NetworkManager
{
  private:    
     BookDisplayKinds m_BookDisplayKind;/
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. You can `include` the header where 'SettingManager::BookDisplayKinds' is declared. Another approach can be forward declaring the `SettingManager::BookDisplayKinds` enum in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong that you're not showing us, such as a similar-named header earlier in your include path, for example.  I tried your code (but completed it with the missing headers):

#### `49359142.h`

```
#include <QObject>

class SettingManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum BookDisplayKinds{
        BookDisplay1=0,
        BookDisplay2=1,
    };
    Q_ENUMS(BookDisplayKinds)
};
```

#### `49359142.cpp`

```
#include "49359142.h"

class BookManager
{
  private:
     SettingManager::BookDisplayKinds m_BookDisplayKind;//Error is here
};
```

---

#### Result

```
nice make 49359142.o
g++-8 -std=c++2a -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds    -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5   -c -o 49359142.o 49359142.cpp

Compilation finished at Mon Mar 19 09:31:59
```